# How to call external JS library using \J syntax

Tags: emeditor

I'm trying to encrypt one column of my very big CSV file.

So I'm using JavaScript as the expression on the "Find and Replace" dialog of EmEditor:
https://www.emeditor.org/en/howto_search_replacement_expression_syntax.html

I've correctly identified the regex for selecting the column in each line. Now I've typed the following syntax in the "Replace with" field:

```
\J CryptoJS.AES.encrypt( "\0" , "MySecretPassphrase")
```

But an error appears saying `CrytoJS is undefined`.

How can I call external JavaScript libraries from the "Replace with" field?

If it's not possible, is there any other way to achieve this from EmEditor? (even if I need to use a syntax different than JavaScript)

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can't import third party JS libraries into EmEditor. What I would suggest doing is copying just that column to another file. Then use NodeJS to encrypt each line. Copy the column back into your original file.